# Shadow not showing for UITableVIewCell contains UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, shadow

I am playing around with my first iOS app.

I set up a cell shadow like this:

```
ucell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
ucell.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
ucell.layer.shadowRadius = 1;
ucell.layer.shadowOpacity = .15;
```

Later I add a UIImage view as the background:

```
ucell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:tempImg];
```

Then the shadow of this cell disappears.

Also in the other cells where I have a image view on the left side, the shadow is not showing at the bottom of the image part:
[1 http://imageshack.com/a/img538/6425/01mv70.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img538/6425/01mv70.png)

how can I fix this problem.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens if you changes the shadow to be on the contentView of the cell instead of the cell itself?

Comment: No luck, still not showing the shadow :(

Comment: What does your code look like if you change it? Try turning of clipsToBounds - just note that the image might stick out then.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have added that imageview sticking to the cell's top and bottom. Thats why it is not showing. If you have added that imageview one pixel above the actual cell contentview, it will be shown.